Animating rotation of an Oar or ship rowing paddles
I'm very new here.
I am modelling an ancient Roman Liburna and hit a brick-wall with the oar animation.

I tried this thread here
but it doesn't work for me.
Wondering if it is still valid with the new version of Blender.
This video shows a quick process of how I'm doing it.
As can be seen, the constrains applied aren't properly aligning the object to the empty. I tried many different changes, but no result.
I have started using Blender only some weeks ago.
So not very good with the interface.
If you guys can direct me on how to get the rotation as seen in the thread, it'd be great.
Thanks.

The origin of your oar is not placed in a convenient position, it should be close to the point it is fixed at, or if you want it there, use an helper object placed correctly. Also the track to constraint may need adjustment of the axis being tracked.

Thanks Duarte for the suggestions it helped a lot. Yes, it required to make axis adjustments.
Here's a link to the working prototype.
[link] (https://youtu.be/t2BpOiZuF2A)
